# Identify brown dots on tomato plants

Tags: tomatoes

Can anyone can tell me what this is? Tiny brown dots on tomato leaves and dark spots on some stems.

[image]

Comment: I personally consider it as "aging" (probably it is not). I'm more worries about so expanded tomatoes plant (and leave), but probably it is just because you have so early a so large plant (so not enough sun).